# Segfault when trying to access a boolean inside of a class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
const int PIXEL_WIDTH = 10;
const int PIXEL_HEIGHT = 10;
const int WORLD_X = 64; //WORLD_X * PIXEL WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH if you want the world to be the same size as the screen
const int WORLD_Y = 64;

enum Pixel_Types {
    AIR,
    WALL,
    DIRT,
    STONE
};

class Pixel
{
    int x, y;
    bool affected_by_gravity;
    Pixel_Types type;
    public:
        Pixel() : affected_by_gravity(false), type(AIR), x(0), y(0) {}
        Pixel(int temp_x, int temp_y) : affected_by_gravity(false), type(AIR), x(temp_x), y(temp_y) {}

        int getX() { return x; } //x is 0-63, scales up in the rendering code
        int getY() { return y; } //y is 0-63, scales up in the rendering code

        int getScreenX() { return x*PIXEL_WIDTH; } //x is 0-63, scales up in the rendering code
        int getScreenY() { return y*PIXEL_HEIGHT; } //y is 0-63, scales up in the rendering code

        bool setDeltaX(int temp_delta_x);
        bool setDeltaY(int temp_delta_y);

        void setAffectedByGravity(bool yesorno) { affected_by_gravity = yesorno; }
        bool getAffectedByGravity() { return affected_by_gravity; }

        Pixel_Types getType() { return type; }
        void setType(Pixel_Types what_type) { type = what_type; }//if (type == DIRT or type == STONE) { affected_by_gravity = true; } }
};

std::vector<Pixel> world; //the world is a dynamically allocated thing

Pixel* getPixelFromCoordinates(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > 63) x = 63;
    else if (x < 0) x = 0;
    if (y > 63) y = 63;
    else if (y < 0) y = 0;

    for (int pixel_index = 0; pixel_index < world.size(); pixel_index++) {
        if (world.at(pixel_index).getX() == x && world.at(pixel_index).getY() == y) {
            return &world.at(pixel_index);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

bool Pixel::setDeltaX(int temp_delta_x) {
    if (x+temp_delta_x > SCREEN_WIDTH/PIXEL_WIDTH or x+temp_delta_x < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getPixelFromCoordinates(x+temp_delta_x, y)->type == AIR) {
        x += temp_delta_x; 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Pixel::setDeltaY(int temp_delta_y) { 
    if (y+temp_delta_y > SCREEN_HEIGHT/PIXEL_HEIGHT or y+temp_delta_y < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getPixelFromCoordinates(x, y+temp_delta_y)->type == AIR) {
        y += temp_delta_y; 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void generateWorld()
{
    for (int world_generation_index = 0; world_generation_index < 4096; world_generation_index++) {
        int x = world_generation_index % WORLD_X; //the world is 64 pixels left and right, and 64 up and down. this math is pretty easy and just extrapolates that. also each pixel is 10 pixels across, times 64 pixels = 640 (the resolution)
        int y = floor(world_generation_index / WORLD_Y); //both x and y start at 0
        world.push_back(Pixel(x, y));


        if (x == 0 || x == 63) {
            world.at(world_generation_index).setType(WALL);
        }

        if (y == 1) {
            world.at(world_generation_index).setType(WALL);
        }    

    }
    std::cout << "World size: " << world.size() << std::endl;
}

void createPixel(int x, int y, Pixel_Types type) 
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl << std::endl;
    y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT / PIXEL_HEIGHT) - y; //compensate for the stupid inverted y in opengl
    //if (getPixelFromCoordinates(x, y)->getType() == AIR) {
        getPixelFromCoordinates(x, y)->setType(type);
    //}
}

void physicsOneStep() 
{
    for (int pixel_index = 0; pixel_index < world.size(); pixel_index++) {
        if (world.at(pixel_index).getType() == DIRT or world.at(pixel_index).getType() == STONE) {//if (world.at(pixel_index).getAffectedByGravity()) {
            world.at(pixel_index).setDeltaY(-1);
            //std::cout << world.at(pixel_index).getX() << std::endl;
            //std::cout << world.at(pixel_index).getY() << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

So when I try to run this code (part of a larger project) it occasionally gives me a Segfault on calling `setType(DIRT)` from within `createPixel()`. I know that the values provided to `createPixel()` are within the range that they are allowed to be (0 to 64). It seems to segfault if you click (which calls `createPixel()`) in the same spot twice. The line that the debugger says segfaults is

`void setType(Pixel_Types what_type) { type = what_type; }`

though, I've verified that the values that I have supplied to this are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no dynamic allocation inside the class, having a segfault on such an allocation most certainly occur because the `this` pointer itself is incorrect (NULL or badly allocated). You should get up the traceback when it segfaulted to see how the object on which you called `setType` was allocated. For example, shouldn't the line

```
world.push_back(Pixel(x, y));
```

be

```
world.push_back(new Pixel(x,y));
```

?

Comment: Okay, so I tried this, and also changed the world variable to work with pixel pointers, and I still got a segfault on that same line. I looked into the variables and noticed that `this` was set to `0x0`, and the variables in the pixel class were undefined, even when I used `new Pixel(x,y)`, as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/kFZ8QBL.png and this is what it should look like, as called from `generateWorld()` http://i.imgur.com/QlJ5Wx9.png

Comment: My diagnoses was then correct. You called `setType` on a null pointer. Note that, I didn't said I fixed all the allocation problems with my correction. So get up the stack frame in your debugger to look for when this null pointer comes from.

Comment: The normal stack: http://i.imgur.com/JAV7SSH.png and the stack when I get a segfault: http://i.imgur.com/YoLOhFd.png As you can see the pointer for the pixel is 0x0 in the second image. Would just passing in the pointer for the pixel that I want to work with be something that I could do (as in, not having `setType()` be a function in `Pixel`)?

Comment: Actually, I tried to make the `setType()` function as stated above, and the `0x0` address was still passed in if I clicked in the same spot twice, so this problem must be something that is more underlying. With a bit more investigation I've noticed that `getPixelFromCoords()` is sometimes returning `0`. But, the reason why is beyond me.